# Energy Eigenstate of a Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, quantum-states

What exactly are energy eigenstates?
For something like H = $h\omega \left( \begin{matrix}1 & 2i \\-2i & 4
\end{matrix}\right)$ , what the eigenstates be like the eigenvectors, so $(i\,\,\,2)$ and $(-2i\,\,\,1)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In linear algebra, operators (like the matrix you wrote down) act on vectors. For some matrix $M$ and vector $\vec v$, if $M\vec v = \lambda \vec v$ for some scalar $\lambda$, then we call $\vec v$ and eigenvector of $M$ and $\lambda$ its associated eigenvalue.

In quantum mechanics, the state of whatever system you're modeling is (roughly) represented as a vector in some vector space.  In this context, it is common to refer to vectors as states and eigenvectors as eigenstates.